# How to create a circle of volume in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

My question is: How can we create a button with which you can raise and lower the volume on my player ... which is a circle ... any idea how to do?

[image: circle volume]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a component that implements onTouchEvent. In the onTouchEvent you detect the location and direction of the touch, and you change the rotational position of the graphic, as well as the volume, accordingly. onTouchEvent is documented in the Android API docs under "View".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using OpenGL to get the 2D/3D graphics in. You would then be able to do some sort of interpolation on the range of the button (say a volume control widget using OpenGL) which on increasing or reducing can alter the volume setting of the media player correspondingly.

To alter the volume in your app you can look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html for OpenGL